# Quick Sort algorithm getthing an exception thrown (partially solved)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort, sizeof

My issue is that I get an exception thrown when my array size becomes too big: "Unhandled exception at 0x00F22A67 in lab.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00682F60)." It was recommended that I use vectors instead of arrays, but this did not solve the issue. I added a break and began to debug. That is where I noticed that this occurs when the quickSort function is entered. I'm assuming that, with such a large array/vector size, the stack becomes full as it is partitioned and divided into subarrays. What would be a recommended fix for this?

```cpp
// Insertion Sort
void insertionSort(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int j, temp = arr[i]; // make a copy of a[i]
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) { // starting "moving left"
            if (arr[j] > temp)
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; // inversion detected, move a[j] to the right
            else
                break; // index j is one spot to the left of where temp belong
        }
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
}

// Partition
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right, int pivotIndex) {
    int pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];
    swap(arr[pivotIndex], arr[right]); // move pivotValue to end

    // partition the array. upon finding an element smaller than pivot,
    // swap it ot the next position in the "store"
    int store = left;
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {
        if (arr[i] <= pivotValue) {
            swap(arr[store], arr[i]);
            store++;
        }
    }

    swap(arr[right], arr[store]); // swap pivot to its final position
    return store;
}

// Quick Sort
// std::vector<int> &data, int left, int right
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    // Perform IS when sub array(s) are less than 10
    if ((right - left) < 10) {
        insertionSort(arr, right);
    }
    else {
        int M = (right - left) / 2;
        int j = partition(arr, left, right-1, M);
            quickSort(arr, left, j);    // sort the left of M
            quickSort(arr, j+1, right); // sort the right of M
    }
}

// Check if array has been ordered
bool isOrdered(int arr[], int n) {
    // array with 1 or no elements will always be sorted
    if (n <= 1)
        return true;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int input;

    // Prompt user with catch if input not within bounds
    do
    {
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << " Press 1 to exit the program " << endl;
        cout << " Press 2 to select the array that is sorted in increasing order " << endl;
        cout << " Press 3 to select the array that is randomly sorted " << endl;
        cout << " Press 4 to select the array that is sorted in decreasing order " << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cin >> input;
    } while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4);

    while (input != 1)
    {
        int n = 10000;

        int* a = new int[n];
        int* b = new int[n];
        int* c = new int[n];

        int* a_c1 = new int[n];
        int* b_c1 = new int[n];
        int* c_c1 = new int[n];

        int* a_c2 = new int[n];
        int* b_c2 = new int[n];
        int* c_c2 = new int[n];

        if (input == 2) {
            // Fill array with numbers in ascending order
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = i + 1;
            }

            // create first duplicate array
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a_c1[i] = a[i];
            }

            // get start time for IS
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            insertionSort(a_c1, n);
            // get end time
            auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            double elapsed_time_ns = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end - start).count());
            double elapsed_time_ms = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::milliseconds> (end - start).count());
            // output time to screen
            cout << "Elapsed time of Insertion Sort function: " << elapsed_time_ns << " ns or " << elapsed_time_ms << " ms" << endl;

            // create second duplicate array
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a_c2[i] = a[i];
            }

            // get start time for QS
            auto start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            quickSort(a_c2, 0, n);
            // get end time
            auto end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            double elapsed_time2_ns = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end2 - start2).count());
            double elapsed_time2_ms = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::milliseconds> (end2 - start2).count());
            // output time to screen
            cout << "Elapsed time of Quick Sort function: " << elapsed_time2_ns << " ns or " << elapsed_time2_ms << " ms" << endl;

            cout << "After passing array through Insertion Sort funtion, is it sorted? " << isOrdered(a_c1, n) << endl;
            cout << "After passing array through Quick Sort funtion, is it sorted?     " << isOrdered(a_c2, n) << endl;
            
        }

        else if (input == 3) {
            // seed the PRNG (MT19937) using a variable value (in our case, rd)
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 generator(rd()); // seed by variable input
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, n); // random numbers need to be in range between 1, n 
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b[i] = distribution(generator);
            }

            // create first duplicate array
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b_c1[i] = b[i];
            }
            
            // get start time for IS
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            insertionSort(b_c1, n);
            // get end time
            auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            double elapsed_time_ns = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end - start).count());
            double elapsed_time_ms = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::milliseconds> (end - start).count());
            // output time to screen
            cout << "Elapsed time of Insertion Sort function: " << elapsed_time_ns << " ns or " << elapsed_time_ms << " ms" << endl;

            // create second duplicate array
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                b_c2[i] = b[i];
            }

            // get start time for QS
            auto start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            quickSort(b_c2, 0, n);
            // get end time
            auto end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            double elapsed_time2_ns = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end2 - start2).count());
            double elapsed_time2_ms = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::milliseconds> (end2 - start2).count());
            // output time to screen
            cout << "Elapsed time of Quick Sort function: " << elapsed_time2_ns << " ns or " << elapsed_time2_ms << " ms" << endl;


            cout << "After passing array through Insertion Sort funtion, is it sorted? " << isOrdered(b_c1, n) << endl;
            cout << "After passing array through Quick Sort funtion, is it sorted?     " << isOrdered(b_c2, n) << endl;
        }

        else {
            int temp_1 = n;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                c[i] = temp_1;
                temp_1--;
            }
            
            // create first duplicate array
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                c_c1[i] = c[i];
            }

            // get start time for IS
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            insertionSort(c_c1, n);
            // get end time
            auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            double elapsed_time_ns = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end - start).count());
            double elapsed_time_ms = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::milliseconds> (end - start).count());
            // output time to screen
            cout << "Elapsed time of Insertion Sort function: " << elapsed_time_ns << " ns or " << elapsed_time_ms << " ms" << endl;

            // create second duplicate array
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                c_c2[i] = c[i];
            }

            // get start time for QS
            auto start2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            quickSort(c_c2, 0, n);
            // get end time
            auto end2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            double elapsed_time2_ns = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end2 - start2).count());
            double elapsed_time2_ms = double(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::milliseconds> (end2 - start2).count());
            // output time to screen
            cout << "Elapsed time of Quick Sort function: " << elapsed_time2_ns << " ns or " << elapsed_time2_ms << " ms" << endl;

            cout << "After passing array through Insertion Sort funtion, is it sorted? " << isOrdered(c_c1, n) << endl;
            cout << "After passing array through Quick Sort funtion, is it sorted?     " << isOrdered(c_c2, n) << endl;
        }

        // Prompt user again with catch if input not within bounds
        do
        {
            cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << " Press 1 to exit the program " << endl;
            cout << " Press 2 to select the array that is sorted in increasing order " << endl;
            cout << " Press 3 to select the array that is randomly sorted " << endl;
            cout << " Press 4 to select the array that is sorted in decreasing order " << endl;
            cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cin >> input;
        } while (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4);
    }
    
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but after the `size < 10` case in `quickSort()` you don't return. So you insertion-sort the array and then you also quick-sort it!?

Comment: Also, in the expression `(int)floor((n - 1) / 2)` both the cast to int an the `floor()` invocation are redundant. Integer division produces an integer result. You can replace that expression with `(n - 1) / 2` and get exactly the same result, with fewer operations.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find out where this exception gets thrown?

Comment: So I want to make sure I understand what the question is. It seems like you're asking: "since `sizeof()` doesn't give me the information I need, how do I have the `quickSort` function know the size of the array?" The answer is that you don't need to; the point of the `left` and `right` values is that the algorithm is supposed to ensure that they always represent a valid range of indices.

Comment: Pardon; my third close vote was hasty as I messed up my reading comprehension. I think this is the hint you need: you have `left` and `right` values that indicate the range of indices that will be sorted, and you're going to sort that range using `insertionSort`, and the problem is that you need to know how many values there are. So, can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you how many values there are? Try some example values of `left` and `right` and reason out how many values there are, and then see if you can identify the pattern.

Comment: Alternately: think carefully about the condition you're using to decide when to use `insertionSort`. What information does it actually encode?

Comment: The separate issue is that `insertionSort` is built to sort an entire array, because it just receives a pointer and length (rather than pointer, left and right ends). Think: where in memory does the data start that you wish to `insertionSort`? Can you think of a mathematical rule that gives you the appropriate pointer?

Answer (score 1):

In the quickSort() function, the 2 recursive calls, I do not see the start index.

What is the range of the array being used for sorting?

First recursive call goes from 0 -> j
Second recursive call goes from 0 -> n-j

Isn't that obviously wrong?

Comment: I have edited the question, still getting an endless recursion

Comment: You still have a bug in quick sort while sorting the right side of the partition. index j is already sorted. the partition range should begin at j+1. That being said, your code never reaches the quick sort algorithm since sizeof(arr) is always less than 10. Why couldn't you just use (right - left) as the size of the array.

Comment: Just to add , you don't need the 2 if conditions to recurse into the partition.

Comment: I updated the code again and everything is almost perfect. The sort work, but the partition function works by moving the pivot to the end of the array and for some reason it is not swapping. So the "sorted" output is "After quick sort: 4 5 6 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 13 21 25 25 61 99 77".

Comment: yes , because insertion sort ignores last element .

Comment: I was finally able to figure it out. Thank you for your help. Now I just need to figure out a work around because an exception is still thrown when my 'n' value passes 1000 and for this assignment, I need it to be at 100000. I was recommended to use vectors which I did, but still get the same stack overflow error.

Answer (score 1):

```
swap(arr[right], arr[store]);
```

You're swapping with an index that is out of bounds. Every time you do that the right bound is increased by one. The exception is due to infinite recursion because of this. Making it right - 1 will do the the job in the partition function.

```
int j = partition(arr, 0, n, M);
```

Mention proper bounds. Quick sort is divide and conquer approach. Specifying 0 and n as the bounds every time makes it a whole array without the partition from the previous recursion.